# How to handle socket.io authentication errors with nodejs server and reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

We are trying to display an error when the connection has failed during authentication (wrong JWT token).

For that, we have a middleware on the server that verifies the validity of the token and is expected to return an error if the token is invalid :

```js
io.use((socket, next) => 
{
    jwt.verify(socket.handshake?.query?.refreshToken, process.env.REF_JWT_SEC, (err, decoded) =>
    {
        if(decoded?._id && !err) 
        {
            socket.decoded = decoded._id;
            return next();
        }
        else
        {
            let err = new Error('authentication_error')
            err.data = { content : 'refreshToken error!' };
            return next(err);
        }
    });
});
```

On the client we have multiple `socket.on()` instances :

```js
const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
const socket = io(
  "http://localhost:4000",
  {
    query: { refreshToken },
  },
);
...
export const Chat = () => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect_error", err => {
      console.log(err); // <-- error we're trying to log
    });

    socket.on("error", err => {
      console.log(err); // <-- error we're trying to log
    });

    socket.on("message", ({id, text, sender}) => {
      console.log('# socket io res :', id, text, sender)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect()
    }
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

While trying to trigger the error by sending an **incorrect token** (`"ThisIsSomeIncorrectToken"`), as expected, sending/recieving messages doesn't work. However, **no error is being logged**.

In the client's console we can see the requests to socket.io:
[image: Network requests to the server]

Note that somehow the error shows up in the client logs when I save my reactjs code, but not if I refresh completely the browser or re-render the component.